# Why can't I set a Table variable w/ objSel.Tables.Item(1)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, vbscript

I'm trying to loop through selected tables, rows, columns, and cells.
However, I cant get the Table object to set properly into the variable in the for loop.
I inspected the element `TypeName(objSel.Tables.Item(1)` to validate that the type *IS* of type Table. But I keep getting a "Type Missmatch" error.

Below, you can see the code and the error.
[image]

Second Attempt:
[image]

Comment: Is this in word or outlook? Why if instead of the selection just use the activedocument?

Comment: What is the type of objSel.Tables? it may be incompatible with the `for each` verb, if it does not implement an iterator for instance.

Comment: This is in outlook, but I've imported the Word References. I don't want to modify all tables in the document, just the one i have selected.

Comment: When I inspect the element it just says "Tables". How would I find out if it has an iterator. (I'm relatively inexperienced w/ VB scripting). Note when i do `*.Tables.` the options are: `Add, Application, Count, Creator, Item, Nesting Level, Parent`

Comment: There's something fishy with your usage of the `inspector`  - make sure it's all syntactically correct from application to application.

Comment: I'm able to get past the selector and it does pull back the item, but it doesn't seem to like the type. Do you think it is trying to cast one Table to a different Table type?

Comment: The error in the second attempt looks like it can be fixed by using `Set`: `Set aTbl = objSel.Tables.Item(i)`.

Comment: Thanks Frank, Excellll and Ryastafarian for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It loods like the issue was because it was trying to store a Word.Table into an Outlook.Table.

#### Before (Not Working):

```
Dim aTbl As Table
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To objSel.Tables.Count()
    Debug.Print (TypeName(objSel.Tables.Item(i)))
    Set aTbl = objSel.Tables.Item(i)
    Debug.Print (TypeName(aTbl))
Next
```

#### After (working):

```
Dim aTbl As Word.Table
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To objSel.Tables.Count()
    Debug.Print (TypeName(objSel.Tables.Item(i)))
    Set aTbl = objSel.Tables.Item(i)
    Debug.Print (TypeName(aTbl))
Next
```